# Как сделать что бы описанная функция выполнялось с задержкой в .5s?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет есть такая функция

```
$('.contacts-dropdown').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('show')
    $(this).prev().removeClass('active')
   })
```

Т.е когда c contact-dropdown уберут мышку, удалится класс show. Как сделать что бы класс show удалился через 0.5s после ухода мышки с contacts-dropdown

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то на подобии такого кода:

```
$('.contacts-dropdown').delay(500).removeClass('show');
```